# How to use weighted heatmap in CartoDB?

Tags: carto, heat-map

I would like to make the CartoDB heatmap use weighted values from a column in the dataset. I tried to find the option in the wizards and the docs but I couldn't find anything. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Heatmaps are a variation of Torque maps, maybe you could change the torque-aggregation-function of the Heatmap in order to get the effect that you want. You can find more information about how the Torque spatial aggregation works here:https://github.com/CartoDB/torque/wiki/How-spatial-aggregation-works

Comment: @oriolbx that comment deserves to be in an answer, not in the comments! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @oriolbx suggested in the comments it is possible through the torque-aggregation-function. You can change the standard heatmap CartoCSS like this:

```
/** torque_heat visualization */

Map {
-torque-frame-count:1;
-torque-animation-duration:10;
-torque-time-attribute:"cartodb_id";
-torque-aggregation-function:"round(avg(weight))";
-torque-resolution:2;
-torque-data-aggregation:linear;
}

#your-dataset{
  image-filters: colorize-alpha(blue, cyan, lightgreen, yellow , orange, red);
  marker-file: url(http://s3.amazonaws.com/com.cartodb.assets.static/alphamarker.png);
  [value < 1] {marker-fill-opacity: 0.05;}
  [value < 10] {marker-fill-opacity: 0.1;}
  [value < 100] {marker-fill-opacity: 0.2;}
  [value < 1000] {marker-fill-opacity: 0.4;}
  [value < 10000] {marker-fill-opacity: 0.6;}
  [value < 100000] {marker-fill-opacity: 0.8;}
  [value >= 100000] {marker-fill-opacity: 1.0;}
  marker-width: 7;
}
```

The only differences are the **-torque-aggregation-function**, for which I used my **weight** column, and the **marker-fill-opacity**, that has to be modified to take into account the output value of the torque aggregation function, stored in the **value** variable.